# Listing all AWS SNS Subscriptions recursively using promises

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, recursion

The AWS SDK paginates results by [returning 100 results and a NextToken string](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#listSubscriptions-property). You then call the same method but pass this token and you get the next results. This continues until no token is returned at which point you know you've reached the end of the list.

I need to get all results in Node.js using promises but I'm puzzled as to how the .then() syntax works with recursive calls.

This is what I have so far, which is a plain old non-recursive call:

```
var params = {
    NextToken: null
}
sns.listSubscriptions(params).promise().then((list) => {
    let nextToken = list.NextToken
    if (nextToken) {
        // call this again
    }
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this is an answer that helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35814597/4666784

Comment: @peterschulten that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.